# Datefaceting on multiple value in solr

Tags: solr

In solr, I have two fields one is datetime [Admission_Date] and other string[Name].
I want to do datefaceting on multiple values in one solr query.

Suppose I have 3 records. name="test" ,"test1", "test3".

I want to do datafaceting on all three values in one solr query.

Currently I am using below link:
[http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Date_Faceting:_per_day_for_the_past_5_days](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Date_Faceting%3a_per_day_for_the_past_5_days)

In this I can provide datefaceting on one value in one query.

but is it possible to provide on multiple values in one query?

Thanks in advance,

Sagar Joshi

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look into Range Faceting. Here are some guides:

- [LucidWorks - Range Faceting](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-RangeFaceting)
- [Solr Wiki - Facet By Range](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Facet_by_Range)